# ADFS and MVC Application - SSO

Tags: model-view-controller, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

We have one intranet Application and implemented ADFS authentication on it. We have our custom login form with Username and password and we are authenticated easily using ADFS. we are using windowsmixed endpoint to authenticate

Application, Users and ADFS all are in one domain

Now we want to skip that login page, so if Domain\User1 is logged in on his/her machine , intranet application should authenticated with current windows logged in user automatically without asking username and password when we open it.

Is it Possible and How?

Thanks!!!

Regards,
Darshit Gajjar

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done via IWA in a browser (WS-Fed passive profile). IWA is a function of the browser not ADFS.

You are using WCF (WS-Fed active profile) which has no browser component.